# How much max current does this soldering-iron-station drive from the mains network?

Tags: current, soldering-iron-station

This might sound a simple question, but I'm kind of confused. Here i the device and data sheets:

http://www.velleman.eu/products/view/?id=385738

http://www.velleman.eu/support/downloads/?code=VTSS4N

On its label it is written: 48 Watt 230V ac/50Hz.

Can we say the max current it will drive from the mains hot wire is:

Correction (48 W / 230 V = 0.21 A)

Is 230V ac directly applied to the soldering device's resistance?

Comment: The links ask where I am in the world and then forget where I wanted to go.  Can you post the details here please?

Comment: what do you mean? your link doesnt open?

Comment: It redirects to the "where are you?" page, which then redirects to the home page.  Clicking the link again, in case it saved a cookie, does the same thing again.

Comment: are u in united states of america?

Comment: Yes, but that's irrelevant.  Make sure that anyone in the world can see what you want them to see without you being involved.  In other words, test the links yourself and post everything here that becomes inaccessible to anonymous.  Or just post everything here anyway and use the link solely for attribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

P = EI, so I = P/E = 48/230 = 0.2 Amp.

Since this iron has some kind of temperature control, the incoming AC power will not be connected directly to the iron.

Comment: do you mean there will be a transformer?

Comment: The user manual doesn't give any wiring diagram, but I would expect that there is a transformer, for safety, but that's only a guess.

Comment: because if there is a step-down transformer the calculation for current wouldn't be valid right? you mean a safety transformer with 1:1 ratio?

Comment: The thing will draw 0.2 amps (48 watts) when heating, regardless of the step-down ratio of the transformer, or of whatever other circuit there may be inside the controller.

Comment: The math as shown is correct for input current, regardless of what a transformer might do between that and the iron itself.  There is probably a DC power supply (either step-down transformer + rectifier or switching) followed by a controller that chops up the DC to feed the iron.  The iron itself probably requires more current at less voltage = same power = same heat.

Comment: If there was a DC power supply they would write that DC voltage. Look at laptop adapters, they are also converting 230V ac to lets say 19V dc. They always write dc voltage and power. Im not sure if this device is converting to dc. Are you sure?

Comment: The outputs of laptop adaptors and other wall-wart type power supplies are user-accessible, so do show the DC output voltage and current.  If there is a DC supply inside this soldering iron controller, it is not accessible to the user, so no need for the user to know what its characteristics are.

Answer (score 1):

P = I * U

=>

I = P / U

Hence the correct calculation is 48 W / 230 V = 0.21 A.

Comment: oh sorry thats right, but can we say that would be the max ampere driven from the mains?

Comment: Yes, assuming that the label is correct.

Comment: Do you think 230V ac directly applied to the soldering device's resistance?

Comment: I don't know, I guess probably not. But that has no effect on the calculation of the maximum current.

Comment: Usually these solder irons are run with say 10 ... 24 V, depending on your temperture setting. Besides stepping down the voltage, the transformer and the other components also take care that your electronic components (semiconductors, integrated circuits) aren't damaged by mains spikes.

Comment: Most of these type of station/iron soldering stations use a transformer inside the station. If you could weight it in your hand you could make a fairly safe bet. On the other hand, such transformer-stations often have a the iron connected via a plug. This one does seem to have a fixed connection to the iron.